# How to determine if an unmarked device is 110V or 220V?

Tags: power-supply, reverse-engineering

I have a Chinese laser power supply that the mfg insisted was 110VAC input. The fan runs and everything seems ok, but I only get a fraction of the power out of it (3ma instead of 27ma max). I suspect that it is actually 220V. Is there a way to determine what voltage input a power supply needs? I will open it up if necessary (waiting a day and discharging all the high voltage capacitors of course).

I can tie it into the 220v in my shop, but if it is not rated for 220v it will likely destroy it. Is there any way to know before that point?

Here is the video of my initial test if it is helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOA96iQiC1c

Comment: There are few possible hints (Input capacitors ratings, transformer's spec, rectifiers spec), but nothing absolute, and if you don't trust the manufacturer, do not use their power supply, it is your safety after all.

Comment: More info.  What's the voltage of the output? Is the supply constant current or constant voltage?  It could be the gas mixture in your CO2 laser tube is not right?  Can you put a dummy load on the supply and test it?  If the fan is running, I'd suspect the supply is OK... Is there leakage in your wiring maybe?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, The output is listed as 19kV. I have no way of testing this however. Good idea on the dummy load. I should probably source a 100W 1M resistor. This would also let me check the voltage to some extent.

Comment: I'm not a HV guy, but a resistive voltage divider might work.  If the bottom is the 10 meg of your DMM, then assuming the voltmeter can handle 200 V a divide by 100 would work.  I've got 1 gig ohm resistors... I don't know if they are rated for 20 kV!  Do you have another power supply that works with the tube?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, I do not have a second power supply unfortunately. I may end up buying one before I am done. Yeah getting a single resistor that will drop 19kV is probably not in budget. I will probably string together ten or so high voltage rated 100k 10W resistors in a silicone tube or something. With a known resistance(not high tolerance but better than nothing) and a measured current I should be able to get a pretty reliable voltage measurement.

Comment: Standard laboratory practice is the string of 2-watt resistors in a plastic tube - HV resistors are expensive and a PITA. 50 2-watters at 1/50th your desired value are easy, and you can tack on a lower value to get more division down on the ground side of it.

Comment: Oh boy, operating a Chinese high voltage power supply that does not even have  primary voltage ratings. You are brave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try using an isolated variac transformer with 220vac input, start with an output of 110vac, (set the output before connecting the device).  Once connected slowly increase the output and see if the device climbs toward the expected operating conditions. (Be careful to watch for problems if the other components might be 110v rated as you hinted at.)  Don't go too far if the output is not heading toward the expected value, much better to err on the safe side.

Comment: There should be a disclaimer that says something like "only do this if you're really desperate". A bought device with a vital rating like the primary voltage missing shall be returned. Your advice is only applicable to a vintage device or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your particular situation I would (after double checking that the resistor network for the power supply configuration is correct according to the manual/datasheet) return the power supply to the manufacturer stating that it does not function as expected.

If necessary you may have to look elsewhere for a power supply that does work. After viewing your video you seem to have done a reasonable amount of debugging to try and get it to work, within what is considered safe for such a dangerous piece of equipment.

Comment: Indeed.  Dear ericnutsch:  What's the refund policy on the power supply?  In your country, do goods come with an [implied warranty of merchantability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_warranty)?  Did you use a credit card to pay for the power supply?